# Задача на массивы с++

Tags: c++, массивы

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с задачей. Из массива А удалить нечетные элементы, которые не равны нечетным элементам массива В. 
Пример: Массив А=3, 4, 5; массив В=1, 5, 6 новый массив А = 4 5.
Мои соображения:

```
void main()
{
    int i, n, x, a[100], b[100];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) //n-количество элементов
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> b[i];
    }
    x = n;
    i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] % 2 != 0 != b[i] % 2 !=0) 
        { //Дальше надо начать удалять нечетные элементы неравные В 
        }
    }        
    getch();    
}
```

Comment: Эээ... А откуда у вас берётся значение переменной `n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал вам решение второпях. Естественно, здесь нет никаких проверок на переполнение массива и т.д., это уж сами допишите. Если что не понятно, спрашивайте! =)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <iostream>

    using namespace::std;

   int poisk(int B[], int temp, int n2)
   {
      int k=0;
      for (int i=0; i<n2; i++)
      {
         if (B[i]!=temp)
            k++;
      }
      if (k==n2)
          return 1;
      else
          return 0;
```

}

```
    void del(int A[], int &n1, int i)
    {
        for (i; i<n1; i++)
        {
         A[i]=A[i+1];
        }
        A[n1-1]=0;
        n1--;
    }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
        int A[10];
        int B[10];
        int n1=0,n2=0;
        int temp;

        cout<<"Введите количество элементов первого массива: ";
        cin>>n1;
        cout<<endl<<"Введите количество элементов второго массива: ";
        cin>>n2;

        cout<<"Вводим значения первого массива:"<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<n1; i++)
        {
         cin>>A[i];
        }

        cout<<"Вводим значения второго массива:"<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<n2; i++)
        {
         cin>>B[i];
        }
        cout<<endl;

        for (int i=0; i<n1; i++)
        {
         if (A[i]%2!=0)
         {
             temp=A[i];
            if (poisk(B, temp, n2))
            {
                del(A, n1, i);
                i--;
            }
         }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<n1; i++)
        {
         cout<<A[i]<<endl;
        }
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: После del(A, n1, i) следующие нечётные элементы вроде станут чётными? (лечится просмотром с хвоста)

Comment: Я пробовал запустить Ваш код, но он выводит не правильные ответы(

Comment: Замените функцию Poisk на:
    int poisk(int B[], int temp, int n2)
    {
  int k=0;
        for (int i=0; i<n2; i++)
        {
         if (B[i]!=temp)
             k++;
        }
  if (k!=n2-1)
   return 1;
  else
   return 0;
    }
Тесты:
Первый массив: 1 3 4 6 8
Второй: 1 2 4 6 8
Итог: 1 4 6 8

Comment: Тесты:
Первый массив: 1 3 4 6 8
Второй: 1 2 4 6 8
Итог: 1 4 6 8

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь)

Comment: Всё работает?
Я так понял, вы начинающий программист, поэтому постарался написать код с помощью простых операций. Если же жаждите чего-то неординарного, то спрашивайте у VladD'а (отписался ниже), он мне не раз помогал! =)

Comment: Вы правы. Я буквально недавно погрузился в изучение программирование... Так сказать сложно, но интересно)

Comment: @slim: Если вам помог ответ, почему бы не отметить его принятым?

Comment: @xeeqqw, а за один вызов `del()` можете сделать? 

Т.е. если не вызывать функцию сдвига элементов влево из циклов поиска "хороших".

Оптимизацию поиска (как в set у @VladD) пока опустим.

Comment: @avp: кстати, лучше `unordered_set`, получится скорее в пару раз.

Comment: @VladD, т.е. `set` реализуют деревом, а `unordered_set` хэшем?

С одной стороны я понимаю, что детали реализации принято прятать, но с другой ...

Comment: @avp: насколько я понимаю, да: [`std::unordered_set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) в среднем `O(1)`,  что «намекает» на hashset. Но (как принято в C++) точная структура данных не специфицирована, лишь требования по скорости. `std::set` сначала вроде был на AVL-tree, потом стало модно использовать red-black tree, что сейчас в тренде, я не в курсе.

Comment: @xeeqqw, боюсь огорчить Вас, но функция `poisk()`, не только крайне неэффективная, но и **просто неправильная**. 

Если число встречается в массиве `B[]` несколько раз, то она вернет 1, а не 0.

При тестировании будьте внимательней, тестируйте на более разнообразных наборах данных.

Comment: @avp, вроде программу поправил. Я же обмолвился изначально, что писал на скорую руку, так что извиняйте. Насчёт эффективности: да, думаю функцию poisk можно написать гораздо элегантнее, вы правы! Но я старался ответить на вопрос человека, чтобы он понял (учитывая его уровень знаний), какой смысл писать здесь заумные вещи?! Посоревноваться в элегантности кода мы с вами можем где-нибудь в другом месте, хотя, наверно, я проиграю =)

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать что-нибудь такое: 
 В цикле пробегаете по массиву А. Если элемент массива четный, то записываете его в результирующий массив. Если же он нечетный, то во вложенном цикле бегаете по массиву В и сравниваете текущее значение из A со значениями В. Если в В находится аналогичный элемент, то записываете его в результирующий массив и прерываете вложенный цикл

По окончании всех этих действий массив А  становится равен результирующему массиву

Comment: @DreamChild: (извините, что засоряю ваш вопрос, там лимит комментариев)

Во-первых, помогать с тривиальными проблемами вроде аккуратного обращения с индексами — заведомо тупиковый путь. Человек должен сам порисовать кубики и стрелочки, чтобы понять, как надо. Если выдать ему готовое решение, будет не лучше, а только хуже.

Во-вторых, «высокоуровневое» объяснение _может_ подтолкнуть человека на изучение правильных, адекватных языку средств, что уже хорошо.

В третьих, такой ответ может помочь другим участникам сайта узнать, как же _лучше всего_ решать подобные задачи на C++.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте стандартные контейнеры.

```
std::unordered_set exceptset(except.begin(), except.end());
std::copy_if(src.begin(), src.end(), 
             std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
             [&exceptset](const int i)
             {
                 return !(i % 2 != 0 &&
                          exceptset.find(i) == exceptset.end());
             });
```

Ввод остаётся в качестве упражнения.

Comment: @VladD, решили запугать новичка и отвратить от программирования?

В любом случае, если он не научится сейчас манипулировать битиками в памяти, то в коде подобном Вашему всегда будет делать разные ошибки.

Comment: Тоже правильно. 

Кстати, что меня в подобных задачах ставит в тупик, так это требование **удалить элемент массива**. Что это означает, догадывайся как хочешь...

Comment: @VladD Почему сразу Зелёный Змий? На haskell эти вещи тоже несложно сделать :)
Для простоты вместо массивов -- списки (с массивами букв больше, import надо, да и не только его...)

       [a | a <- [3, 4, 5], even a || a `elem` [1, 5, 6]]

И, кстати, ещё раз. На каком C++? Подозреваю, что в студенческих лабораториях C++11 встречается нечасто.

Comment: @VladD, вы забыли exceptset в замыкание добавить.
Вдобавок, передовать int по ссылке дороже, чем по значению.

Comment: @dzhioev: и правда :-) Спасибо, обновил.

Comment: @alexlz: list comprehensions обычно встречаются именно в функциональных языках. (кстати, в C# LINQ используется чаще всего в варианте LINQ-to-objects, а не LINQ-to-SQL). черты ФП тут в иммутабельности данных и подъёме функций/предикатов на элементах до преобразований/фильтров последовательности элементов. а система записи, она всего лишь синтаксис. хотя, вы правы, здесь играет не ФП, а удобство list comprehensions.

Comment: @VladD это, конечно, здорово но вы не забывайте о том, что данная задача, скорее всего, задана преподавателем, и этот самый преподаватель такое решение скорее всего, не примет, сказав, что "мы это не проходили". И в общем-то будет прав, так как задача, скорее всего, предназначена для закрепления элементарных знаний по циклам и массивам

Comment: @DreamChild: Оставаться на уровне знаний такого преподавателя — позорно. Если я умею решать задачу с интегралами, мне не нужно закреплять таблицу умножения на 2, а преподаватель, который этого не понимает, профессионально непригоден, и должен быть немедленно отстранён от работы. Иначе будут [вот такие](http://ru-marazm.livejournal.com/3591670.html) примеры.

---
А объяснять аккуратное обращение с индексами и копирование значений в массиве циклом `for` мне скучно, это элементарщина для детского сада.

Comment: @VladD, решение, конечно, красивое. Но, не толкает ли оно С++ на путь уже пройденный такими языками, как Пролог и АПЛ? 

Вот мне кажется, что пусть красивые, но непонятные программы просто отпугивают "массы". Получается что-то элитарное ... и просто перестает развиваться. Да, набранная крестами инерция очень большая и возможно застой и забвение им уже не грозит.

--

Возвращаясь к задаче. Если считать, что удаление в массиве это сдвиг **"нужных"** влево, то возможно ли столь же элегантно, как в Вашем ответе, и за один проход выразить такой алгоритм?

Comment: @avp: Хм, по-моему, именно туда C++ и движется. Путь простых и ясных программ с предсказуемой эффективностью остаётся в pure C.

---
Для сдвига в массиве есть функция [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), она именно сдвигает в конец ненужные элементы in place. (Работает и с нативными массивами!)

Comment: @VladD, Вы думаете `remove_if` эквивалентна коду

     for(i = 0, j = 0; i < n1; i++)
        if (is_good(a1[i], a2, n2))
           a1[j++] = a1[i];
     n1 = j;

который сдвигает все в нужные позиции за один просмотр массива? Я не знаю.

--

Боюсь, мои комментарии здесь закончились, поэтому сразу скажу, что вместо массива a2, конечно, можно использовать его hashset.

--

А Вы считаете, что "сложные" для быстрого понимания массовым пользователем программы действительно нужны? 

Засада тут в том, что если этот стиль укоренится в "массах", то неочевидных ошибок будет много (мягко говоря).

Comment: @avp: да, равносилен, если верить http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove (Possible implementation -> second version).

---
Насчёт сложных программ — даже не знаю. Для тех, кто прошёл через ручное управление индексами, такой подход экономит кучу кода, поскольку делает то, что программист сам бы сделал вручную. Будет ли он вреден для тех, кто не прошёл? С другой стороны, пользователи Windows (да и Ubuntu) не начинают с комстроки и `copy *.txt D:\`, а сразу с абстракций графического интерфейса, вредит ли это им?

Comment: @avp: мы ведь тоже не представляем, как именно работает кэш процессора и pipelining. Ассемблер даёт нам модель последовательного выполнения с неиерархической памятью, а процессор выполняет в самом деле не это (и разница заметна для многопоточных программ). Как глубоко _нужно_ уметь разворачивать абстракции? Я не знаю, но для себя стараюсь знать и понимать как можно больше.

Comment: >Оставаться (не быть, а именно оставаться)

@VladD, судя по всему, ТС увидел С++ буквально месяц назад, а вы ему лямбда-функции и итераторы скармливаете. Его препод - это всего лишь учитель, который, фигурально выражаясь, рассказывает второклассникам про таблицу умножения, что, собственно, и должен делать. Или вы хотите, чтобы второклассникам на уроках математики рассказывали про дифференциальное исчисление? А что касается того, что лично вам скучно - ну ведь, согласитесь же, этот вопрос был задан ТСом для решения своих собственных проблем, а не ваших, при всем уважении

Comment: @avp А причём тут Пролог и APL? Пролог -- язык совсем из другого семейства, и сравнивать его с C++ бессмысленно. А вот насчёт элитарности APL -- это круто. Когда он был в расцвете, им в массовом порядке пользовались совсем не программисты. И не ворчали на непонятность. (Ну может и ворчали, но обилие программ и аппаратуры на рынке этого ворчания не учитывали). Правда это было давно.

@VladD я согласен с @DreamChild -- вопрос был про элементарные вещи, и объяснения, что есть более крутые инструменты в языке, вряд ли может вызвать у вопрошающего что-либо кроме раздражения. Всё это потом.